# Pinterest Integration in iOS

Tags: ios, pinterest

I have integrated Pinterest in my application. Pinterest app is retrieving image (from url which I have shared) in popup but its not retrieving description text when Pinterest button is clicked in application. And it is forcing to enter description manually. I want description to be retrieved from application.

```
[_pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com/500/400"]
                        sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com"]
                      description:@"Pinning from Pin It Demo"];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
_pinterest = [[Pinterest alloc] initWithClientId:@"1234567" urlSchemeSuffix:@"prod"];

[_pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cs303404.vk.me/v303404440/1ae3/ZkKQLEFGeyY.jpg"]
                        sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://placekitten.com"]
                      description:@"Pinning Test from My Own App - Renish Dadhnaiya"];
```